# HTML and JavaScript not working correcty

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning javascript and I have been on HTML for some time now. I know I have successfully coded a right JavaScript code for my log in form.

Here is my JavaScript code:

---

```
<script>
function login(){
    var username=document.getElementById('usrnm');
    var password=document.getElementById('pass');
    if(username=="abc"){
        if(password=="123"){
            window.location.href="mypage.html"
        }
        else{
            window.location.href="error.html"
        }
    else{
        window.location.href="error.html"
    }
}
</script>
```

---

And here is my HTML form:

---

```
<form name="input" method="get">
<b>Username:</b>
<br>
<input id="usrnm" type="text" name="usrnm">
<br>
<br>
<b>Password:</b>
<br>
<input id="pass" type="password" name="pswrd">
<br>
<br>
<center>
<input id="login" type="image" src="login.png" value="login" onclick="login()">
```

---

When I click on the Log in button. It only reloads the same page it is in but as you can see, I intended to call "mypage.html". I'mm just starting to learn JavaScript so if there are any obvious reasons why my code wont work, be easy. Thanks =). I know my JavaScript works because when I tried inserting `onclick="login()"` to the line `<form name="input" method="get"`> the code directs me to "error.html" when I type on the Username field or Password field.

Comment: Add `.value` to `username` and `password`. Like this `if(username.value == "abc")`

Comment: You have a typo in your if condition, you are missing `}` of main if

Comment: you can shorten code `if(username=="abc" && password=="123" ){ success page } else { go error page }`

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810874/how-to-get-an-input-text-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

You are not getting the element values, just the elements. Add `.value` to the end of your `document.getElementById(id)` method calls.

Answer (score 4):

You JS does not work as intended. You are selecting *elements*, but not their *values*. Try changing to the following:

```
<script>
function login(){
    var username=document.getElementById('usrnm').value;
    var password=document.getElementById('pass').value;
    if(username=="abc"){
        if(password=="123"){
            window.location.href="mypage.html"
        }
        else{
            window.location.href="error.html"
        }
    }
    else{
        window.location.href="error.html"
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: that is _exactly_ my answer

Comment: @DKM,@imulsion we posted almost simultaneously, sorry. Copy-pasted OP's code, didn't notice, now edited.

Comment: it Happens :) no worries ;)

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev Neustroev, Still does not work. If you want I can post my disorganized, 657 line code. Cx

Comment: @CarloSolomonFernandez try to debug your `login` function to see what exaclty happens.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev the url becomes: <file:///F:/WD/Speedhunter/speedhunter.html?usrnm=abc&pswrd=123&x=0&y=0> this must be something right?

Answer (score 0):

Get the usrnm id, pass id values as

```
var username=document.getElementById('usrnm').value;
var password=document.getElementById('pass').value;
```

**OR**

Otherwise pass if condition as

```
if(username.value == "abc"){
    if(password.value == "123"){
      .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code

var username=document.getElementById('usrnm').value;

var password=document.getElementById('pass').value;