# Assigning PHP Variables To Javascript Variables Not Working

Tags: javascript, php

I am currently having trouble with this. I would like to make one of my variables in Javascript have a PHP value. Here is what I mean:

```
<script>
    JSvariable = <?php echo $PHPvariable; ?>;
</script>
```

For some reason that is not working. Here is my full (snippet) of code:

```
<script>
    currentreplyid = <?php echo $allpostcomments[$key]['replyid']; ?>;
    $('#parentcommentholder').val(currentreplyid);
</script>
```

I am sure it is some stupid mistake, but I can not seem to find it! What is the problem? Thank you!

**PS** `#parentcommentholder` is an input field, and it just had the value 0 after the field is supposed to of been changed.

Here is some source:

```
<?php
$postcommentsquery = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent = :parent AND postid = :postid ORDER BY datecreated DESC";
$postcommentsparams = array(':parent' => $allreplies[$key]["postid"],
                            ':postid' => $postid);
try{
    $postcommentsstmt = $connection->prepare($postcommentsquery);
    $postcommentsresult = $postcommentsstmt->execute($postcommentsparams);
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$allpostcomments = $postcommentsstmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($allpostcomments as $key => $value) {
?>
    <script>
    var currentreplyid = <?php echo $allpostcomments[$key]['replyid']; ?>;
    $('#parentcommentholder').val(currentreplyid);
    </script>

    <input id="parentcommentholder"></div>
```

Comment: You forgot to use the `var` keyword. Are there *any* errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Have you made sure $allpostcomments contains the correct array keys (e.g. var_dump($allpostcomments) ) to ensure the keys exists

Comment: I tried the `var` keyword, but that did not fix anything. Yes the key is correct, and in the console there are 0 errors.

Comment: The $PHPvariable is really set?

Comment: the variable is an int.

Comment: Is your script at the top, or bottom, of the page?

Comment: Below where the PHP variable is being declared, so towards the bottom of the page.

Comment: Try putting the $PHPvariable in a <p> inside the HTML. See if there's an echo.

Comment: what result do you get when you do `var_dump($allpostcomments);` ? placed after `$allpostcomments = $postcommentsstmt->fetchAll();`

Comment: @fred-ii I have fixed the big problem with it I believe, now I am trying your code and it says the function is not defined. Any idea why? It occurs when it runs this line `var currentreplyid = "<?php echo $allpostcomments[$key]['replyid']; ?>";`

Comment: sorry, JS isn't my strong point. Plus, you didn't tell me what var_dump gave out. add a function name to the js. `function function_name(){...}` type of thing then call that function.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is just a giant file from the database. Would you still like to see it? The field I am grabbing is there because I have used the same method before, and it has worked. The field is a plain old int.

Comment: the problem doesn't seem to be db related, least I don't think so. but the var_dump shouldn't be that big. Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11811079/ and other answers in that page and may help show you how to build a function. Again,.. JS isn't my bag but I am slowly getting around to it. See if Manwal can help. He may not be around right now.

Comment: Ok Thank You. Yea it is very odd, I have written functions before and they work. It is just that when I add that one like to THAT specific function it all stops.

Comment: @Fred-ii I would LOVE to thank you! Your harassment into doing `var_dump()` made me figure out the issue. Well not `var_dump()` but `print_r()`, anyhow I figured out for some reason I was looking over using the wrong list. Thank You!!!!

Comment: lol my harassment - that's a bit harsh hahaha! but I'm glad you were able to figure out what the issue was. *Cheers* and you're welcome ;-) Edit/P.s.: You should post your own answer then.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forgot for give quotes `'` or `"`. Use following:

```
<script>
    var JSvariable = '<?php echo $PHPvariable; ?>';
    //or
    var JSvariable = "<?php echo $PHPvariable; ?>";
</script>
```

**Reason:** If php variable contains string and if while assigning it to javascript variable we shall not give quote like:

```
<?php $PHPvariable = 'String';?>
var JSvariable = <?php echo $PHPvariable; ?>;
```

Will transform into :

```
var JSvariable = String;//which will give error in javascript
```

But this will work fine if PHP variable contains a numeric value like:

```
<?php $PHPvariable = 2;?>
var JSvariable = <?php echo $PHPvariable; ?>;
```

Will transform into :

```
var JSvariable = 2;//which will work perfect
```

---

Complete code should be:

```
<script>
    var currentreplyid = "<?php echo $allpostcomments[$key]['replyid']; ?>";
    //or if you are sure your variable contains int value
    var currentreplyid = parseInt("<?php echo $allpostcomments[$key]['replyid']; ?>");
    $('#parentcommentholder').val(currentreplyid);
</script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81312/discussion-on-answer-by-manwal-assigning-php-variables-to-javascript-variables-n).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below instead of using javascript (as I don't think you need it):

```
<?php
$postcommentsquery = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent = :parent AND postid = :postid ORDER BY datecreated DESC";
$postcommentsparams = array(':parent' => $allreplies[$key]["postid"],
                            ':postid' => $postid);
try{
    $postcommentsstmt = $connection->prepare($postcommentsquery);
    $postcommentsresult = $postcommentsstmt->execute($postcommentsparams);
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$allpostcomments = $postcommentsstmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($allpostcomments as $key => $value) {
?>
<input id="parentcommentholder" value="<?php echo ((int)$allpostcomments[$key]['replyid']>0) ? $allpostcomments[$key]['replyid'] : 0; ?>" />
<?php
}
?>
```

If your defiantly sure $allpostcomments[$key]['replyid'] is bringing back a value, this should work without any issues.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply! Thing is though, I really do need the variables :)

Comment: Have you tried putting script below input and putting a blank value="" on the input

Comment: No, sorry. I need to grab the value in Javascript from PHP because of where I need it. That is sadly not going to work. It is not THAT simple (I wish it was :D).

Comment: If this input is also in a foreach statement make sure the id is set as a unique id for each result