# How can I get HTML element value by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="gallery_re_form">
  <form action="http://gall.dcinside.com/?/forms/comment_submit" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="comment_write" id="comment_write" />
      <div style="display:none">
          <input type="hidden" name="ci_t" value="625752bb366f010c56e506e5d0f93822" />
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="ehqo_C" id="ehqo_C" value="spam_key" />
      <input type="hidden" name="spam_key" id="spam_key" value="rhkdrhgkwlak!!" />
      <input type="hidden" name="fb8f95190d2b70480acb309f91653d7e4416d4f99a0b67a0b866f06087fdec4588f68fe210675e74919d2ecc50e08f1fd6f75119" id="fb8f95190d2b70480acb309f91653d7e4416d4f99a0b67a0b866f06087fdec4588f68fe210675e74919d2ecc50e08f1fd6f75119" value="b9d3cc45576e30144d8f299fdc61356552989b3aba08238c811b1d3183a104cc2d1d3984af72c4f2eaa2738ca41819d05533731a" />
      <input type="hidden" name="service_code" value="21ac6e96ad152e8f15a05b7350a24759b5606fa191c17e042e4d0175735f4c61d63153c3ce7b4eb89b565a7f6a04ad0667df75f39625ab6fe0816d23f4bed5387546b52d6874b5c201e54df7b5db9187219b048cffc9ef8a106febabfba125eff122df732d9cc52fcaae8b11c42ff5f6fd5ef81901df4103827e7233615992141c180be76852634d53b60c6f911ccdfc762b3db554d8ee36528547bceede30697120c5291acb255a" />
      <br />
      <div class="re_input">
          <div>
              <ul>
                  <li>
                      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="re_name re_in" onfocus="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'" title="nickname" />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="re_pw re_in" onfocus="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'" title="password" />
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

I'm trying to rewrite google chrome extensions. I want to get `#spam_key` s `#service_code`s value in this HTML response.

I have not used JavaScript.

How can I get HTML element id (spam_key, service_code) and value by JavaScript?

Comment: Where are `id = spam_key value and id = service_code` ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Mistakes in formatting were hiding them from view. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an input text value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810874/how-to-get-an-input-text-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to retrieve the spam_key element and service_code element's values?

```
var spam_key = document.querySelector('#spam_key');
var service_code = document.querySelector('input[name=service_code]');

console.log(spam_key.value);
console.log(service_code.value);
```

You can learn more about selection element from javascript at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 5):

DOM has a `document` object , you can use it like this to get the HTML element what you want

```
document.getElementById("id")
```

Now to get value, just use `value` property of this element.

```
document.getElementById("id").value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of an HTML input element using:

```
var spam_key = document.getElementById('spam_key').value;
var service_code = document.getElementById('service_code').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It should give the value of spam_key

```
document.getElementById('spam_key').value;
```

Comment: Don't use both javascript and jquery.

Comment: Yup i was confused b/w val() and value .. now recheck and changed it @Alexandru-IonutMihai

Comment: @Ashu just a pointer, please check other answers before you post. Does you answer points or add something more to that other answer have addressed? If no, then your answer is just redundant.

Comment: @Rajesh I was answering when there were not any Answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery included you can get it by following:  `$("#spam_key").val()`