# Trying to validate JavaScript input using OnClick and a function. No matter what is entered, it says the format is correct.

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, input

I have an HTML file and an external JavaScript file. I have input from the user in the HTML and on the click on the validate button, the courseValidation() function is called. The problem is with the if statement. When the input does not match myRegExp, it should write that the format is incorrect to the page, but it always writes Correct Format, regardless if it is correct or not. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I'm just learning so no negative comments please.

HTML File:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Validation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="course.js"></script>
    <p>Enter Course Information:</p>

    <input id="courseCode" type="text">
    <button onclick="courseValidation()">Validate</button>

        <p id="course"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

External JavaScript File:

```
function courseValidation() {
var courseCode = document.getElementById("course").innerHTML;
var myRegExp = /\D{3}.\d{3}#\d{4}_\D{2}-\d{4}/;

if (courseCode.match(myRegExp)) {
    document.write("Incorrect Format");
} else {
    document.write("Correct Format");
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an input text value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810874/how-to-get-an-input-text-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not retrieving the value of the input correctly.  `var courseCode = document.getElementById("course").innerHTML;` should be `var courseCode = document.getElementById("courseCode").value;`.

Also, your `if` statement is the wrong way around.  It should read:

```
if (courseCode.match(myRegExp)) {
    document.write("Correct Format");
} else {
    document.write("Incorrect Format");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The ID of your input is **courseCode** not course and you are using .innerhtml, it should be .value

`var courseCode = document. getElementById('courseCode).value`