# How to get a textbox value to the data-amount in Razorpay Using with Angularjs..?

Tags: angularjs, razorpay

[image: Angularjs with Razorpay]
Am stuck with the payment gateway of Razorpay manual checkout with AngularJS. In every page it's showing direct entry of paid amount, but I want to get the value from the input box to the amount:''.

How can I do that? I have tried but it's not working. It's working with prefill of contact and email, but not working with amount:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an input text value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810874/how-to-get-an-input-text-value-in-javascript)